# Passport.js login event function not being called

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, passport.js

I am using the following code in express with passport:

```
var GAuth = require('passport-google-oauth');

passport.use('google', new GAuth.OAuth2Strategy({
    clientID: GID,
    clientSecret: GSECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/google/callback"
},
function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done){ // not running
    console.log('callback');
    console.log('id: ', profile.id);
}));

router.get('/google', passport.authenticate('google', {
    scope: [
        'email',
        'profile'
    ]
}));

router.get('/google/callback', function(req, res) { // this runs
    res.send('Logged in through Google!');
});
```

Even though the login appears to be working fine on the outside, in that I go to the permissions page for google, then get directed to the callback page. I cannot get the callback function to run, so what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't you have a POST defined in your router for "/auth/google/callback"?

Comment: Why would I need one?

Comment: You have a callbackURL defined in passport.use().  Your user is sent to their website.  Once they've filled in the information the user is redirected back to this URL that you've supplied.  So create that POST.  Something like router.post('/auth/google/callback').

Answer (score 1):

```
router.get('/google/callback',
        passport.authenticate('google', {
            successRedirect : '/home',
            failureRedirect : '/'
        })
);
```

This should work.